# How can I access a method defined with new keyword in a derived class

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding

I have the following classes:

```
class SearchEngine
{
    public virtual void Search()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base Class");
    }
}

class Google: SearchEngine
{
    public override void Search()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Google Class");
    }
}

class Yahoo: SearchEngine
{
    public new void Search()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("new method in Yahoo Class");
    }
}
```

And I call them this way:

```
SearchEngine s1 = new SearchEngine();
SearchEngine s2 = new Google();
SearchEngine s3 = new Yahoo();

s1.Search();
s2.Search();
s3.Search();
```

And I get the following results:

```
Base Class
Google Class
Base Class
```

My question is how to access the `Search()` method from the `Yahoo` class?
(And yes I know this is a bad idea to use the `new` keyword like this and I know this not overriding a class)

Comment: "And yes I know this is bad idea to use new keyword like this and I know this not overriding a class". Than why are you doing it anyway? The problem can´t be solved unless you either omit `new` or use `Google s1 = new Google();` or `Yahoo s2 = new Yahoo();` resp. The `new` keyword only works when casting your instance to the derived class. Convcerting it to the base-class leads to calling the base-method.

Comment: The answer is "use `override` instead of `new` on `Yahoo.Search()`. The answer to "no, seriously, how do I do it wrong" is some kind of Lovecraftian nightmare like this: `public static void Search(SearchEngine eng)
        {
            if (eng is Yahoo)
                (eng as Yahoo).Search();
            else
                eng.Search();
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you need to change:

```
SearchEngine s3 = new Yahoo();
```

to:

```
var s3 = new Yahoo();
```

or:

```
Yahoo s3 = new Yahoo();
```

*Your `new` method is not 'accessible' from the base class. That is the **whole point** of `new` when specified on a method.*

Comment: `dynamic` could also be used, but the above options are preferred.

Comment: To add to above answer the following code can be used to access base class method: `((SearchEngine)s3).Search();`